# Undefined arg in octave function call (YES IT'S A SCRIPT FILE)

Tags: octave

ANSWER

```
eulerballistic(motion, [0;100;0;-9.8;0], 10)
needs to be
eulerballistic(@motion, [0;100;0;-9.8;0], 10)
               ^
```

When I copy and paste these two functions into the cli, I get "error: v undefined"
When I issue "run proj3b.m", same problem
I know about the difference between a script file and a function file.
When I make proj3b.m into a function file properly, I get the same error.

Using octave 6.4.0

proj3b.m

```
1+1;
function z = motion(t, v)
  x2 = 0;
  y2 = -9.8;
  z = v + [v(3); v(4); x2; y2; 1]*t;
  return
endfunction

eulerballistic(motion, [0;100;0;-9.8;0], 10)
```

eulerballistic.m

```
function z = eulerballistic(f, z0, deltat)
z = z0;
i = 1;
while z(2,i) > 0
   zprime = f(z(5,i), z(:,i))
   z(:,i+1) = z(:,i) + deltat*zprime;
   
   i = i + 1;
   if i > 100
       break;
   end
end
z = z(:, 1:end-1);
end
```

Comment: While I've already figured out the answer to the question, why should the question be closed?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The callsite needs the qualifier @ in front of the function name.